# How to update pagination template of knppaginatorbundle after ajax query

Tags: ajax, symfony, pagination

Im using **knppaginatorbundle** to create pagination. I have created a jquery code to select data with ajax.

Everything is okay when I click on the page number , the content is loaded with the correct data.
But I have a problem , The pagination template is not changed after after ajax query:

- previous and next links values must changed
- current page must be disabled
- and other changes that need to be done ...

How can I do this ?

```
public function listAction($page, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $qb = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Travel')->getListTravels();
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $qb, $request->query->get('page', $page), 3
    );

    //ajax request
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

        $view = $this->renderView('@App/Frontend/Travel/list.html.twig', array(
            'pagination' => $pagination
        ));

        $response = new JsonResponse(array('ok' => $view));
        return $response;
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Frontend/Travel:travel-list-view.html.twig', array(
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    ));
}
```

I have added an attr data-target to pagination template like this:

```
<a data-target="{{ page  }}" href="{{ path(route, query|merge({(pageParameterName): page})) }}">{{ page }}</a>
```

**View**

```
//.....
<div id="mydiv">

   // list.html.twig contains the loop
   {% include "AppBundle:Frontend/Travel:list.html.twig" %}

</div>
<br>
{{ knp_pagination_render(pagination) }}
//....

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("ul#pagination a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataTarget = $(this).attr("data-target"); // each <a> has attr named data-target contains num of page
            var hash;
            hash = 'page=' + dataTarget;
            window.location.hash = hash;

            if (window.location.hash != "") {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: Routing.generate('frontend_travels_list', {'page': dataTarget}),
                    success: function (msg) {
                        if (msg["ok"] === undefined) {
                            alert('error');
                        } else {
                            $("#mydiv").html(msg["ok"]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

**Route**

```
frontend_travels_list:
path:     /travels/{page}
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:TravelFrontend:list, page: 1 }
options:
    expose: true
```

Comment: The knppaginatorbundle is not designed to be updated through javascript.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: I dont know but probably use an javascript library like jPaginate: http://tympanus.net/jPaginate/

Answer (score 2):

If someone else needs a solution there 2 ways.

1. You can use that bundle https://github.com/nacholibre/knppaginator-ajax
2. You should build new pagination string in controller and send it in `JsonResponse` as a param. Then replace pagination element in DOM via jQuery on success.

For SF 4.3 you can use my approach

1. To be able to inject the `Processor` in *controller* you have to add alias for autowiring in `services.yaml`

```
Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Helper\Processor: '@knp_paginator.helper.processor'
```

2. Based on injected `PaginatorInterface` you should build your `$pagination` object (`PaginationInterface`)
3. Use `Processor` to build the *context* array for Twig.

```
$paginationContext = $processor->render($pagination);
```

render method expects `SlidingPagination` object, but got `$pagination` which is `PaginationInterface` - however it seems that is ok

4. Get the Twig and render a final *string*

```
$twig = $this->get('twig');
$paginationString = $twig->render($pagination->getTemplate(), $paginationContext);
```

Example of working controller

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $view = $this->render('@App/Frontend/Travel/list.html.twig', array(
        'pagination' => $pagination
    ))->getContent();
    $paginationContext = $processor->render($pagination);
    $twig = $this->get('twig');
    $paginationHtml = $twig->render($pagination->getTemplate(), $paginationContext);
    $response = new JsonResponse(['view' => $view, 'paginationHtml' => $paginationHtml]);
    return $response;
}
```

then in jQuery

```
success: function (msg) {
    if (msg["ok"] === undefined) {
        alert('error');
    } else {
        $("#mydiv").html(msg["view"]);
        $("#myDivContainingPagination").html(msg["paginationHtml"])
    }
}
```